# Google login authentication button not working, Firebase

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web

I am an electrical engineering student and have to code a database for my senior design project. I am writting a small website to access this database to demo it. On the website I have a google login button on a javascript website (https://smartamberalert.web.app/) that is not working. I click the button and nothing happens.

here is my javascript code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event =>{
    const app = firebase.app();
    
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    
    const testPost = db.collection('posts').doc();
    
    testPost.get().then(doc =>{
            const data = doc.data();
            document.write( data.title + '<br>')
            document.write( data.createdAt)
    })

//console.log(app)});

function googleLogin() { const provider = new  firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)

    .then(result =>{
        const user = result.user;
        document.write('Hello ${user.displayName}');
        console.log(user)
    })
    .catch(console.log)}
```

it is the googleLogin function that my problem should be in.

Here is my html code:

```
Welcome to Firebase Hosting

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- update the version number as needed -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-app-compat.js"></script>
<!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-auth-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-database-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-firestore-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-functions-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-messaging-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-storage-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-analytics-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-remote-config-compat.js"></script>
<script defer src="/__/firebase/9.17.2/firebase-performance-compat.js"></script>
<!-- 
  initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded, set useEmulator to false
  to avoid connecting the SDK to running emulators.
-->



</script src = app.js>

<button onclick ="googleLogin()">
  Login in with google
</button>
```

`

I was following the tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9kRgVxULbag&list=PLg3EctrW99v2bRSrkALXrTWFH_fva1xvv&index=34&t=325s&ab_channel=Fireship) for firebase and working to get the google authentication function to work. The button will be displayed on the website but does not execute anything when clicked. I was expecting the regular google sign in popup window to appear when clicked

Answer (score 1):

If you check the JavaScript console of your browser after click the button, it shows:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: googleLogin is not defined

That gives a pretty good starting point to figure out what's going wrong, the code can't find `googleLogin`.

From a quick scan that may be because you've declared that function **inside** the `addEventListener` callback. You'll want to declare it as a top-level function:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
    const app = firebase.app();

    const db = firebase.firestore();

    const testPost = db.collection('posts').doc();

    testPost.get().then(doc => {
        const data = doc.data();
        document.write(data.title + '<br>')
        document.write(data.createdAt)
    })
}); // 

function googleLogin() {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(result => {
            const user = result.user;
            document.write('Hello ${user.displayName}');
            console.log(user)
        })
        .catch(console.log);
}); //
```

Comment: Ok first off thnk you for teaching me about the javascript console in my web browser. I did not know that existed. Second I am going to edit the code cause its not one to one as I have it my app.js because I messed some of the formatting up. I have a lot more eperince in C++ and python. Does function declaration work similarly to C++ as it does in JS?

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're facing with the Google login button on Firebase might be related to the authorized domains for the OAuth client ID. Here are some steps to follow:

**Authorized Domains for OAuth Client ID:**

**Firebase Console:**

- Go to the Firebase Console.
- Navigate to your project.
- Click on "Authentication" in the left menu.
- Go to the "Sign-in method" tab.
- Enable "Google" as a sign-in provider.
- Check the "Authorized domains" section and make sure it includes both your - - Firebase Hosting domain and your local development domain.

**Authorized Domains on Google Cloud Console:**

- Visit the Google Cloud Console.
- Open the "APIs & Services" > "Credentials" page.
- Find the OAuth client ID used for Google Sign-In.
- Add the Firebase Hosting domain (.firebaseapp.com) and your - local development domain (localhost:3000 or whatever your local server uses) - to the list of authorized JavaScript origins.